# building a dict of lists Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I am reading through a csv file, and i have to build a dict of lists in which the key is the stock ticker and the value is a list of closing prices for that ticker. I am having trouble sorting through the tickers by highest and lowest prices for each stock.

The intended output is:

```
>GOOG:  180.38 difference (672.93-492.55)
>LNKD:  100.82 difference (270.76-169.94)
>AAPL:  36.74 difference (133.0-96.26)
>FB:  25.76 difference (98.39-72.63)
>MSFT:  9.32 difference (49.61-40.29)
```

My sample csv table file:

```
>Ticker  Date       Open       High     Low     Close     Volume
>GOOG    25-Sep-15  629.77    629.77    611     611.97    2174009
>GOOG    24-Sep-15  616.64    627.32    612.4   625.8     2240098
```

My code which is not producing intended behavior. I am grappling with looping through the keys in the dict and sorting them by max-min value:

```
file_data = open('../python_data/stock_prices.csv').readlines()[1:]
stock_dict = {}

def price_diff(key):
    change_price = max(stock_dict[key]) - min(stock_dict[key])
    return (change_price)


for line in file_data:
    line = line.split(',')
    ticker = line[0]
    if ticker not in stock_dict:
        stock_dict[ticker] = []
    stock_dict[ticker].append(float(line[5]))

sorted_keys = sorted(stock_dict, key=price_diff, reverse=True)
#print(sorted_keys)

for key in stock_dict:
    print(key, round(max(stock_dict[key]) - min(stock_dict[key]),2))
```

Comment: Do you know pandas, http://pandas.pydata.org/? You should consider using pandas instead of parsing the csv yourself unless you do it as an exercise

Comment: Hi zyxue, thanks for the quick response. I'm doing it as an exercise.

Comment: You are not supposed to sort a dictionary, instead of `sorted(stock_dict)`, try `sorted(stock_dict.items())`

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted_items = sorted(stock_dict.items(), key=lambda (k, v): max(v) - min(v), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @zyxue for the feedback.  After much research, I came to this conclusion and am getting the intended output.

```
file_data = open('../python_data/stock_prices.csv').readlines()[1:]
stock_dict = {}

def price_diff(key):
    change_price = max(stock_dict[key]) - min(stock_dict[key])
    return (change_price)

for line in file_data:
    line = line.split(',')
    ticker = line[0]
    if ticker not in stock_dict:
        stock_dict[ticker] = []
    stock_dict[ticker].append(float(line[5]))

sorted_keys = sorted(stock_dict, key=price_diff, reverse=True)
for key in sorted_keys:
    min_val = min(stock_dict[key])
    max_val = max(stock_dict[key])
    change_val = round(max(stock_dict[key]) - min(stock_dict[key]),2)
    print("{}: {} difference ({} - {})".format (key, change_val, max_val, min_val))
```